# bootstrap-vue is opening before data is updated to api call

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-cli, bootstrap-vue

Is there a way to wait until my data of **teamId** is updated before opening the bootstrap-vue modal? At the moment on the first click to open the modal, the table in **ModalResults** is blank, on the second click, it's populated with the table data correctly, using **teamId** in the get api call. The data is always one click behind the actual click of the **teamId** clicked.

parent component:

```
    <tr v-for="(item,i) in standings"
                :key="i"
                :class="defineColor(item)"
                @click="getTeamId(item.team.id)"
                v-b-modal="'modalId' + i">

<ModalContent :standings="standings" :teamId="teamId" />
...
data() {
    return {
      teamId: Number
    };
  },
methods: {
    getTeamId(teamId) {
      console.log("league Table: ", teamId);
      this.teamId = teamId;
    },
```

child component ModalContent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-modal :id="'modalId' + i" v-for="(item,i) in standings" :key="'teamDetails'+ i"> 
     <ModalResults :results="results" />
    </b-modal>
...

export default {
  name: "ModalContent",
  props: {
    standings: Array,
    teamId: [Function, Number]
  },
  components: { ModalResults },
  data() {
    return {
      results: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getResults(teamId) {
      getData.getTeamResults
        .get(teamId + "/matches?status=FINISHED")
        .then(response => {
          this.results = response.data.matches;
          console.log("this.results: ", this.results);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  },

  watch: {
    teamId() {
      let teamId = this.$props.teamId;
      console.log("teamId watched: ", teamId);
      teamId && this.getResults(teamId);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to call `this.$bvModal.show(id)` inside the get api request, after the response, to ensure that the `teamId` has a value first before opening the modal.
[bootstrap-vue modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal)

Parent Component:

```
           <tr
            v-for="(item,i) in standings"
            :key="i"
            :class="defineColor(item)"
            @click="getTeamId(item.team.id, i)">

<ModalContent :standings="standings" :teamId="teamId" />

...

data() {
    return {
      teamId: Object
    };
  },

methods: {
    getTeamId(teamId, index) {
      let teamIdObj = {
        teamId: teamId,
        teamIndex: index
      };
      return (this.teamId = teamIdObj);
    },
```

In child component watch the object prop, save it to the data, then use `this.$bvModal.show("modalId" + teamId.teamIndex);`:

```
methods: {
    getResults(teamId) {
      getData.getTeamResults
        .get(teamId.teamId + "/matches?status=FINISHED")
        .then(response => {
          this.results = response.data.matches;
          console.log("this.results: ", this.results);
          console.log("getResults object: ", teamId);
          this.$bvModal.show("modalId" + teamId.teamIndex);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
watch: {
    teamId() {
      this.teamId = teamId;
      console.log("teamId watched: ", this.teamId);
      this.getResults(this.teamId);
    }
  }
```